# XCode UIActionSheet image

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimagepickercontroller, uiactionsheet

I am creating a `UIButton` and when the user clicks on it, the camera should pop up and allow the user to take a photo. I decided to add a `UIActionSheet` which allows the user to choose wether they want to choose a photo from the album, or whether they want to take a photo using the camera. Before I added the action sheet the button worked fine, when the user shaped the photo, the background image of the button was replaced by the photo taken by the `UIImagePicker`. But after I added the action sheet now the `UIButtons` image is not being replaced by the images taken from the `UIImagePicker` or from the users photo library

here is the associated code,

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
[self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:NO];

[self.usernameField becomeFirstResponder];
uploadPhotoButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

[uploadPhotoButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"uploadphotoicon"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

uploadPhotoButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 80, 80);

uploadPhotoButton.clipsToBounds = YES;

uploadPhotoButton.layer.cornerRadius = 80/2.0f;
uploadPhotoButton.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:.102 green:.737 blue:.612 alpha:1.0].CGColor;
uploadPhotoButton.layer.borderWidth = 2.0f;

[self.view addSubview:uploadPhotoButton];
[uploadPhotoButton setCenter:CGPointMake(160, 128)];
[uploadPhotoButton addTarget:self action:@selector(uploadPhotoButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];






 - (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
if (buttonIndex < 2) {
    UIImagePickerController * imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    UIImagePickerControllerSourceType type;

    switch (buttonIndex) {
        case 0:
            type = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
            break;
        case 1:
            type = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    imagePicker.sourceType = type;
    imagePicker.delegate = self;

    [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:^{ }];
}

 }
 - (IBAction)signupDone:(id)sender {
     NSString *username = [self.usernameField.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
NSString *password = [self.passwordField.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

if ([username length] == 0 || [password length] == 0 /*|| [email length] == 0*/){
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Oops!" message:@"Please enter a username, password, and email!" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
     [alertView show];
}
else {
    PFUser *newUser = [PFUser user];
    newUser.username = username;
    newUser.password = password;

    [newUser signUpInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Sorry" message:[error.userInfo objectForKey:@"error"] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [alertView show];
        }
        else {
            [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        }
    }];

  }



  }
  -(IBAction)uploadPhotoButton:(id)sender {

UIActionSheet *sheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Select Photo" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Nevermind" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"From Library", @"From Camera", nil];
[sheet showInView:self.view];



  }
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {


uploadPhotoButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];


uploadPhotoButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 80, 80);

uploadPhotoButton.clipsToBounds = YES;

uploadPhotoButton.layer.cornerRadius = 80/2.0f;
uploadPhotoButton.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:.102 green:.737 blue:.612 alpha:1.0].CGColor;
uploadPhotoButton.layer.borderWidth = 2.0f;

[self.view addSubview:uploadPhotoButton];
[uploadPhotoButton setCenter:CGPointMake(160, 128)];
[uploadPhotoButton addTarget:self action:@selector(uploadPhotoButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


userImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
[uploadPhotoButton setImage:userImage  forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];



[self uploadImage];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to create another button,

Only you need to  declare uploadPhotoButton in interface for global use in this controller and just replace the method below :

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker 
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];      
    UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    [uploadPhotoButton setImage:chosenImage  forState:UIControlStateNormal];
//    [self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

    [self uploadImage];
}
```

In this code I first diss miss the image pickerViewController and just set the image on my button.